# Can using a hex key to disassemble LEGO Technic pieces cause damage?

Tags: technic, disassembly, tools

Does using the right size [hex key (Allen key)](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_key) to speed up the disassembly process cause damage to the LEGO Technic pieces?

Comment: In my experience, growing up with them, you can always make a Lego disassembly tool out of more Legos, and then take the tool apart.  You might need to be clever with some of them, but there is always a way.  And you don't risk damage by using a harder material.  You can still bend things though, or break them if your tool isn't designed very well and you use too much force, so you need to be careful with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Yes

A hex key, being tough metal, is inherently a danger to ABS plastic. Using it to push axles and pop connections will eventually scratch and wear down your parts, something you don't want with technic pieces.

Comment: Having used small pliers to get axles out, we should really come up with plastic tools to solve these problems.

Comment: @tl8 what are you trying to get the axle out of? Lego have a tool for taking elements apart that includes a stub of axle for pushing them through. The limit tends to come attempting to get an axle-connector or 2-axle out of a dead-end element.